# Why does std::initializer_list in ctor not behave as expected?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, initializer-list, ctad

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    auto v = std::vector{std::vector<int>{}};
    return v.front().empty(); // error
}
```

See [online demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ofYv85EoP)

However, according to Scott Meyers' *Effective Modern C++* (emphasis in original):

> If, however, one or more constructors declare a parameter of type
> `std::initializer_list`, calls using the braced initialization syntax
> strongly prefer the overloads taking `std::initializer_lists`. ***Strongly***.
> If there's any way for compilers to construe a call using a braced
> initializer to be a constructor taking a `std::initializer_list`,
> compilers will employ that interpretation.

So, I think `std::vector{std::vector<int>{}};` should produce an object of `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` rather than `std::vector<int>`.

**Who is wrong? and why?**

Comment: CTAD for `std::vector{std::vector<int>{}}` founds copy/move constructor.

Comment: Resolves to calling the copy constructor.

Comment: https://cppinsights.io/s/05a45bbb fix: `auto v = std::vector{{std::vector<int>{}}};` https://cppinsights.io/s/7a34c18e

Comment: Why does the ctor with `std::initializer_list` not take the priority as Scott said? @Jarod42

Comment: Did you mean : auto v = std::vector<std::vector<int>>{ std::vector<int>{} }; that will create the vector you want.

Comment: Why does CTAD not work in such a case?@PKramer

Comment: What compiler are you using? Which version of it?

Comment: CTAD does work exactly how it should, just not as you expected. It finds the best (simplest) match for your code

Comment: Does he talk about CTAD or regular constructors calls?

Comment: @Jarod42 I think he does in his example the type of std::vector is left open to be deduced from the arguments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Meyers is mostly correct (the exception is that `T{}` is value-initialization if a default constructor exists), but his statement is about **overload** resolution.  That takes place after CTAD, which chooses the **class** (and hence the set of constructors) to use.

CTAD doesn’t “prefer” initializer-list constructors in that it prefers **copying** to wrapping for nestable templates like `std::vector` or `std::optional`.  (It’s possible to override this with deduction guides, but the standard library uses the default, as one might expect.)  This makes some sense in that it prevents creating strange types like `std::optional<std::optional<int>>`, but it makes generic code harder to write because it gives

```
template<class T> void f(T x) {
  std::vector v{x};
  // …
}
```

a meaning that depends on the type of its argument in an **irregular** and **non-injective** fashion.  In particular, `v` might be `std::vector<int>` with `T`=`int` or with `T`=`std::vector<int>`, despite being `std::vector<std::deque<int>>` if `T`=`std::deque<int>`.  It’s unfortunate that a tool for computing one type based on some others is *not* usable in a generic context.

Answer (score 6):

`auto v = std::vector{std::vector<int>{}};` actually creates a `std::vector<int>` because it uses `std::vector` copy constructor. It is interpreted by the compiler as:

```
auto vTemp = std::vector<int>{};
auto v = std::vector<int>( vTemp );
```

So `v` ends up being a `std::vector<int>`, not a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`.

As reported by "P Kramer" and "Marek P" in comments, the following syntaxes will help any compiler accomplishing what you expect:

```
auto v = std::vector{{std::vector<int>{}}};
auto v = std::vector<std::vector<int>>{ std::vector<int>{} };
```

Comment: Why does the ctor with `std::initializer_list` not take the priority as Scott said?

Comment: That may not be the first time a compiler does not respect what Scott says.  Note that MSVC compiler even refuses to compile the first line, it reports `use of class template requires template argument list`...and with argument list there would be no more ambiguity.

Comment: Except for the suggestions, this merely restates the situation in the question.  That “interpretation” (which gets the value category and lifetime of the argument wrong) doesn’t illustrate *why* `std::vector<int>` is chosen.